# linking with glew static lib mingw-w64 on linux

Tags: c++, linux, glew, mingw-w64

I am cross compiling a win32 version of my 3d project on Ubuntu 32 bit, and having trouble linking with glew static.

I generate libGLEW.a for mingw with the provided configuration file in the glew 1.12 package:

> make SYSTEM=linux-mingw64

rename it as libGLEW_win32.a in my project lib directory,
add a compiler define flag :

> GLEW_STATIC

compile all modules in Codeblocks. The link command sent by cb is:

> i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix -L/usr/local/lib
> -L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -o ../bin/pgm.exe obj/Bar.o obj/Cache.o obj/Camera.o obj/Config.o obj/Fab.o obj/Font.o obj/main.o obj/Math.o
> obj/Mesh.o obj/OpenGL.o obj/Selector.o obj/Shadow.o obj/Shader.o
> obj/System.o obj/Texture.o obj/Tile.o -std=c++0x -static-libstdc++
> -static-libgcc -lodbc32 -lwsock32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lcomctl32 -lctl3d32 -lodbc32 -ladvapi32 -lodbc32 -lwsock32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid ../lib/libGLEW_win32.a ../libAntTweakBar_win32

But still I get undefined references for all glew fonctions (and also AntTweakBar but lets focus on glew).

> référence indéfinie vers  __glewGenBuffers
> référence indéfinie vers  __glewBindBuffer
> référence indéfinie vers  __glewBufferData
>
> ...
>
> référence indéfinie vers TwInit
> ...

I did a hex dump of libGLEW_win32.a and found all the glew fonctions there as expected with the __ prefix. The file is 670582 bytes long which is coherent for that lib. It is the only file named like that on my system so there is no possible confusion there.

Probably a very basic omission but I am embarassed to admit I have been at it for a while now and I don't see what's missing.

Comment: one possibilty is missing library, another is that you might need to reorder the list of libraries (the order matters with g++, not so with visual c++)

Comment: Reordering the libraries is one of the first things I tried, and it did not change anything. If I was mising a library that glew depends on, I would get other symbols missing than the glew ones.

Comment: I also tried the reimp path to convert glew32.lib provided in a windows binary package into a glew32.a ->same result. I noticed though that there is also a glew32s.lib. This one is bigger (2MB) while the other one is 600KB but it crashes reimp. Apparently glew32s.lib is the static one I need, so I am stuck again. Anybody had luck generating a static glew library for mingw one way or another?